# Starting Apache Velocity Localization/Internationalization (i18n)

Tags: apache, spring, localization, internationalization, velocity

I have a great difficulty finding documentation on how to implement internationalization/localization with Apache Velocity. I checked Velocity documentation and did online research, but I can't find supporting material on how to organize and support localization using .vm (Velocity template) files and properties.

**Can someone please direct me to the right resource/documentation/book that describes how to implement localization using Apache Velocity?**

I'm trying to do as much as I can up-front research and reading before starting coding.

Thanks,
partizan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use VelocityTools.

http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/2.0/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/ResourceTool.html

It's also likely that Spring provides some velocimacro or context object that helps with i18n, as Spring generally has a lot of support for i18n

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying to make use of VelocityTools 1.4 but keep getting an error message that it can't find bundle for base name. I've created a new entry here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221161/velocitytools-error-java-util-missingresourceexception-cant-find-bundle-for

May be you can help me?