# VelocityTools error - "java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name WEB-INF.conf.resources.ss_messages, locale en_US"

Tags: apache, spring, localization, internationalization, velocity

I'm trying to integrate VelocityTools.ResourceTool to localize velocity template but whatever I use as the 'bundles' parameter I keep getting the following error:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name 
WEB-INF.conf.resources.ss_messages, locale en_US
```

I'm using VelocityTools v1.4. Here are my configurations:

Tool config `/WEB-INF/conf/misc/velocity/toolbox.xml`

```
<tool>
  <key>test</key>
  <scope>request</scope>
  <class>org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.ResourceTool</class>
  <parameter name="bundles" value="WEB-INF.conf.resources.ss_messages"/>
  <parameter name="locale" value="en_US"/>
</tool>
```

Bundles:

```
\WEB-INF\conf\resources\ss_messages_bg_BG.properties
\WEB-INF\conf\resources\ss_messages_en_US.properties
```

The two files have simple content:

```
full.name=\u0421\u0442\  (for bg_BG.properties)
full.name=Joe Blow       (for en_US.properties)
```

My Velocity template has this code:

```
HELLO $test.full.name
```

I tried different values for the `name="bundles"` above i.e., `/WEB-INF/conf/resources/ss_messages` and `./conf/resources/ss_messages` (going to the root dir and then referencing the ss_messages bundle).

Also, I tried putting my ss_messages.properties bundle files in a `resources` folder in the root and use the `value="resources"` instead, but nothing seems to be working...still getting the same error message.

What am I doing wrong?! Is it that the `toolbox.xml` file is not in the root? I've been using successfully the `toolbox.xml` throughout my application up until now.

Answer (score 2):

The resources should be on the classpath, and configured as such.

See the [`ResourceTool` API docs](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/2.0/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/ResourceTool.html).

Comment: Thanks for bringing it up, I'll make sure I fully use it from now on. I always want to give the deserved credit to people for their help.

Comment: As for your answer, I've been using the ResourceTool API doc as a reference, but I don't understand how I can add a whole folder i.e. my_resources as a bundle using Velocity. So far all the .vm files have been added individually to the classpath using Spring org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource. I did some research on that but I don't seem to be finding a solution tailored to my problem.

Comment: I've asked the follow up question here:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233781/adding-folder-to-classpath-in-velocity-using-spring-framework

Comment: Dave's right.  put the bundles in the classpath, not WEB-INF.